# How to pad a string with leading zeros in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, rounding

I'm trying to make `length = 001` in Python 3 but whenever I try to print it out it truncates the value without the leading zeros (`length = 1`). How would I stop this happening without having to cast `length` to a string before printing it out?

Comment: It depends how you've got `001`. `length = 001` is the same as `length = 1' (number) and to get `001` you should use some string formatting (see answers). But `length = '001'` is different, it's a string and you can get number via `int(length)`.

Answer (score 207):

Make use of the `zfill()` helper method to left-pad any string, integer or float with zeros; it's valid for both [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) and [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill).

It important to note that Python 2 is [no longer supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

*Sample usage:*

```
print(str(1).zfill(3))
# Expected output: 001
```

*Description:*

When applied to a value, `zfill()` returns a value left-padded with zeros when the length of the initial *string* value less than that of the applied *width* value, otherwise, the initial *string* value as is.

*Syntax:*

```
str(string).zfill(width)
# Where string represents a string, an integer or a float, and
# width, the desired length to left-pad.
```

Comment: Have been coding in python for 5 years and I have never come across this function. Great info.

Comment: There's also `str(x).rjust(3, '0')` which is exactly equivalent in speed and you can pad with any character

Answer (score 169):

Since python 3.6 you can use f-string :

```py
>>> length = "1"
>>> print(f'length = {length:03}')
length = 100
>>> print(f'length = {length:>03}')
length = 001
```

Comment: Safer to use `print(f'length = {length:>03}')`  (note the `>`) as this example would fail if length were a string, eg. `length = '1'`

Comment: For large datasets, note that the top answer (zfill) is moderately faster than this method given an integer input and about 3x faster if your input is already formatted as a string.

Answer (score 48):

There are many ways to achieve this but the easiest way in Python 3.6+, in my opinion, is this:

```
print(f"{1:03}")
```

Comment: Could you please explain this syntax, or link where I may read more about it?

Comment: @Cherona https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: I find this the easiest method. The "3" part dictates the number total digits. so {1:03} would display 001. If it was {123:03} then it would display 123. If it was {123:04} then it would display 0123, etc...

Comment: hey that really is the slickest way!

Answer (score 13):

Python integers don't have an inherent length or number of significant digits. If you want them to print a specific way, you need to convert them to a string. There are several ways you can do so that let you specify things like padding characters and minimum lengths.

To pad with zeros to a minimum of three characters, try:

```
length = 1
print(format(length, '03'))
```

Answer (score -8):

I suggest this ugly method but it works:

```py
length = 1
lenghtafterpadding = 3
newlength = '0' * (lenghtafterpadding - len(str(length))) + str(length)
```

I came here to find a lighter solution than this one!

Comment: try this: `print(f"{1:03}")`